# "Out of Bounds" Error while calculating the mean gene

Tags: octave

This is my first time trying to complete work in Octave. I have attempted to complete "for loops" to get the mean of each  and then subtract this to centre the results in the 25 samples of the 5 items. I get the right figures, however I also get an out of bounds error (indicated below). Can anyone help me please?

> ```
> error: TrialPartB: A(I,J): row index out of bounds; value 6 out of bound 5
> ```

Comment: You should mention if your question is homework for school and that you have restrictions (using loops, no built-in function)

Answer (score 2):

You have populated your `G_all` structure with only 5 data members, but then, when you calculate the mean, you loop `i=1:25`. There are only 5 members, so when it gets to member 6, it fails with the 'row index out of bounds' error.

You need to limit the for loop to be just the size of the data, perhaps using `rows(G_all)` instead of `25` as the limit of the loop.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Assignment requires no inbuilt functions such as "mean" but must use loops, so trying to think on my feet. I will look at my rows. Each Gene A-E have 25 samples, so I think I probably confused myself.

Answer (score 1):

As rolfl already explained you are trying to access row 1..25 but G_all only has 5 rows.

But apart that problem you shouldn't calculate mean in a for loop but use the function "mean" instead.

```
a=[4 1 6];
mean(a)
  ans =  3.6667
```

If you want to remove the mean from an vector just use "detrend":

```
detrend(a, 0)
ans =
   0.33333  -2.66667   2.33333
```